# Landscape showing 1 computer has ESM disabled

Tags: landscape, esm, ubuntu-pro

Landscape shows 1 computer has ESM disabled

The computer in question appears to have ESM enabled

I tried to reattach my pro subscription and even renamed
/var/lib/ubuntu-advantage and /var/lib/landscape/client.

Where do I go next?

```
ua status --all  
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION  
cc-eal           yes       disabled  Common Criteria EAL2 Provisioning Packages  
cis              yes       disabled  Security compliance and audit tools  
esm-infra        yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure  
fips             yes       disabled  NIST-certified core packages  
fips-updates     yes       disabled  NIST-certified core packages with priority security  updates  
landscape        yes       n/a       Management and administration tool for Ubuntu  
livepatch        yes       enabled   Canonical Livepatch service  
realtime-kernel  yes       n/a       Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated
```